# Не работает VueJS на главной веб-странице в приложении с Flask

Tags: javascript, python, vue.js, flask, jinja2

Есть небольшое приложение на Flask и VueJS со структурой:

```
static
|- vue.js
templates
|- index.html
server.py
```

Содержание файла server.py:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template

app = Flask(__name__, static_folder = "static")
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret!'

@app.route('/')
def get_main_page():
  return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
 app.run()
```

И содержимое файла index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <script src="/static/vue.js"></script>
 <title>Title</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="app">
   {{ message }}
  </div>

  <script>
   var app = new Vue({
     el: '#app',
     data: {
      message: 'Hello Vue!'
     }
   })
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Вообщем, после загрузки веб-страница ничего не показывает, она полностью белая.

Comment: Согласен с вами, это скорее дубликат, хоть и вопрос не по Django.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Шаблон рендерится шаблонизатором Jinja2, в котором двойные фигурные скобки используются для подстановки переменных. Так как в контексте отсутствует переменная `message`, вместо неё вставляется пустое место. Поэтому, когда наступает очередь работы Vue, он не знает куда вставлять строку 'Hello Vue!'